# Location.href called twice

Tags: javascript, html, drupal-7

I am working on a Drupal project. I need to navigate to a differnt page on button click. I have the following button element in a HTML file.

```
<a href = # id="createbutton" style=margin-left:40px;font-size:80%;>Create New Path</a></h1>
```

And the corresponding handler:

```
$("#createbutton")
.button()
.click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.href = 'http://localhost/drupal/?q=admin/waldendrupal/infograph';
});
```

Whenever I click on the button, the page is loaded twice. The JavaScript in the new page to be loaded is run twice which is problematic.

Can someone tell me what neds to be done to rectify this so that the page is loaded only once.

Comment: *Always surround attribute values with quotes.*

Comment: Why are you calling this a button when it is quite clearly a link and why not simply put the href into the link?

Comment: Thanks. Adding the link location to the href attribute instead of "#" helped.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like this:

```
<a href="#" id="createbutton" style=margin-left:40px;font-size:80%;>Create New Path</a></h1>

$("#createbutton").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.href = 'http://localhost/drupal/?q=admin/waldendrupal/infograph';
});
```